# How can I set an EList as an input in JFace TableViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp, emf

This is my first SO question. I hope i provide enough details.
I have an EMF Model with a class called ScopeContainer, which has two containment References as `EList`s of Different Types.

I have generated the

- model
- model.edit
  and
- model.editor

codes with the Genmodel

I am trying to show the contents of one of those lists in a `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer` with only one Column.

This can't be a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List` since i want to be able to edit those entries.

```
TableViewer viewer;
AdapterFactory adapterFactory = storage.getDomain().getAdapterFactory();
AdapterFactoryLabelProvider labelProvider = new AdapterFactoryLabelProvider(adapterFactory);
AdapterFactoryContentProvider contentProvider = new AdapterFactoryContentProvider(adapterFactory);

viewer.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
viewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
viewer.setInput(project.getScopecontainer().getFilters());
```

When I set the input as the the ScopeContainer Object. I can see all the objects in both lists
When i set the input as the `EList<Filter>` the Table is empty.
What do i have to do to set the Input of the TableViewer as EList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to override `AdapterFactoryContentProvider.getElements()` to return an array of `Filter` elements (derived from the `EList<Filter>` input).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I provide the code I implemented as an Answer. I am greatful for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I overrode the getElements Method Like this:

```java
public class EListContentProvider<T> extends AdapterFactoryContentProvider{

    public EListContentProvider(AdapterFactory adapterFactory) {
        super(adapterFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        Object[] arr = null;
        if(inputElement instanceof EList) {
            arr = ((EList<T>) inputElement).toArray();
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the class *org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider* or the class *org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.ObservableListContentProvider*, depending on if your list is supposed to change or not.

Those content providers do exactly what you are asking for: manage a collection input for a table or a viewer.

Comment: The ObservableListContentProvider will not use the EMF generated item providers.